# Losing "consecutive days" Credit on SF

Tags: support, questions, login, account

In going for the all-important "Enthusiast" and "Fanatic" badges on SF, I've been pretty (er, um) enthusiastic about checking in daily.  Tonight I checked my SF account to see that I'm back to only one day of consecutive visits.  Tonight is Saturday, and I noticed this at 9pm Eastern Time.  Yesterday was Friday, and I know that I used SF while I was at work.

Where is this 'loss' coming from?  Are you using GMT to calculate the days?

Comment: As an aside, I was slightly disappointed to discover that there is no badge for an entire year's worth of daily activity.

Comment: HA!  But what's beyond "Fanatic" except for "Certifiable" or "Committed/Institutionalized"...

Comment: There's a reason some refer to it as *CrackOverflow*.

Comment: @jscott ...but the badges are _sooooo_ worth it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An SE [day starts at 00:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start).  I am not sure if you, or anyone except diamonds or moderators, can check a user's visitation activity log.  This issue has caused some confusion for [other users as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge/24888).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  +1 and Answered.